# Why isn't Spark textFile method reading the whole text file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
class Cleaner {
  def getDocumentData() = {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("linkin_spark")
      .setMaster("local[2]")
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
      .set("spark.rdd.compress", "true")
      .set("spark.storage.memoryFraction", "1")

    val CorpusReader = new Corpus()
    val files = CorpusReader.getListOfFiles("/home/DATA/doc_collection/")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val temp = sc.textFile(files(0).toString())
    println(files(0).toString())

    var count = 0
    val regex = """<TAG>""".r
    for (line <- temp ) {
      line match {
        case regex(_*) => {
          println(line)
          count += 1
          println(count)
        }
        case _ => null //Handle error - scala.MatchError
      }
    }
    println(s"There are " + count + " documents.") // this comes out to be 0
  }
}
```

I have a list of text file that I have to read. They are XML-like files so, I need to extract the relevant text. Since, they are not standard XML files I thought of using regex to get the text. Every document start with a `<TAG>` tag. So I tried to count no. of documents in a file which will be equal to no. of `<TAG>` matches in the file. The function above does the same thing. Originally the file has 264 docs but when I run the function I get 127 or 137, either of the numbers. It does not seem to reading the whole file. Also `count` at the end comes out to be 0.

I am Scala/Spark newbie.

**UPDATE:**

```
var count = sc.accumulator(0)
val regex = """<TAG>""".r
for (line <- temp ) {
  println(line)
  line match {
    case regex(_*) => {
      count += 1
      println(s"$line @ $count")      //There is no "<TAG> @ 264" in the output
    }
    case _ => null
  }
}
println(s"There are " + count.value + " documents.")
```

This change in the program gives me the correct value of `count` i.e. 264 but the file id printed correctly!! It appears to start somewhere from the middle and end somewhere in the middle.

**UPDATE II:**

This has something to do with threads. The `SparkConf()` has been initialised using `local[2]` which means 2 threads, if I am not wrong. As soon as I changed it to `local[1]` I got the correct answer but I cannot use one thread.

File appears like this:

```
<TAG>
<DOCNO> AP890825-0001 </DOCNO>
<FILEID>AP-NR-08-25-89 0134EDT</FILEID>
<TEXT>
Some large text.
</TEXT>
</TAG>
<TAG> // new doc started
```

How should I correct this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is a closure problem. Each node gets its own version of the `count` variable. You want to use [`accumulators`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators) or simply perform a `reduce`

Created by:

```
val tagCounter = sc.accumulator(0, "tagCount")
```

Updated by: (not readable on the nodes)

```
tagCounter += 1
```

Readable on the driver by:

```
tagCounter.value
```

Following your update:

```
var count = sc.accumulator(0)
val regex = """<TAG>""".r
val output = for (line <- temp ) yield {
  //println(line)
  line match {
    case regex(_*) => {
      count += 1
      //println(s"$line @ $count")      //There is no "<TAG> @ 264" in the output
      line
    }
    case _ => "ERROR"
  }
}
println(s"output size:{output.count}")
println(s"There are " + count.value + " documents.")
```

UPDATE AFTER SEEING THE INPUT FORMAT:

You may end up at the whim of using `wholeTextFiles` to guarantee ordering. Otherwise the distributed nature means that ordering is often not guaranteed, but if you can guarantee ordering (possibly custom partitioner or custom InputFormat), then something like this should work:

```
sc.parallelize(list)
  .aggregate(Nil : List[String])((accum, value) => {
    value match {
      case regex(_*) => accum :+ value
      case _ => {
        accum match {
          case Nil => List(value)
          case _ => accum.init ++ (accum.tail :+ value)
      }
    }
  }, _ ++ _)
```

Comment: I understand the problem with `count`. What about the text file reading? Why is it not reading the whole text file?

Comment: That is for `count`. Are you sure it isn't reading the files?

Comment: I printed the matches, and it does print but only 127 out of 264. I checked it manually that the file has 264 `<TAG>`s but the function only prints 127.

Comment: This is weird. I ran the program with you suggested modification and the final answer of `count` is 264 but when did `println(line)` inside the for loop it did not print the whole file!! Does this have to do anything with the nodes, that you were talking about? I am on a single system as of now.

Comment: I updated my answer using your updated code. If the count of the RDD is equal to the `count.value`, then it is working and just acting weird on your machine. Typically I have seen println work even if distributed across two cores (on the same machine), but it is very possible that this is a distributed problem, yes

Comment: OK, then what are you trying to do? I cannot imagine you are planning to simply print the results. I cannot help you any more without more specifics. The yield that I posted will result in a new RDD with the data loaded in if that is what you want?

Comment: Ok. see I have a file with tagged data. I was trying to read the file line by line to extract text but this has to done in sequence. Using multiple thread/nodes I will have to combine the results like you told me to do for `count`. But how will I do that for the text?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78837/discussion-between-justin-pihony-and-animesh-pandey).

Comment: I just updated the answer...the distributed nature hurts the ordering...so wholeTextFiles is probably your best bet